# Solution verification for hypothesis testing and confidence interval problem

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I have the following problem for which I'm not sure my solution is correct:

There's a random sample of size n = 10 observations over a normally distributed population with standard deviation $\sigma=2$:

8.7, 7, 4, 7.6, 3, 8.1, 6.4, 6.1, 9.4, 6.2

- Find 96% confidence interval for the population mean
- Test the hypothesis $H_0: \mu=7.5$ against $H_a: \mu \neq 7.5$ with significance level $\alpha=0.01$. Find approximation of the observed p value.

**My Solution:**

We are looking for real numbers **l** and **u** s.t.:

$P(l < \hat \theta < u) = 0.96$, where $\hat \theta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-n \theta}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}} \sim N(0,1)$.

We are looking for $z_{0.2}$ which from the z-score table is: 2.055. Therefore:

$$-2.055 < \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-n \theta}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}} < 2.055 \equiv -2.055\sqrt{40} < \sum_{i=1}^n X_i-n \theta < 2.055\sqrt{40} \equiv \\
-12.996 - 66.5  <-10\theta < 12.996-66.5 \equiv 5.350 < \theta < 7.94.
$$

**For the second part:**

We set two z-scores: $z_1=-2.325$ and $z_2=2.325$ from which we construct a two-tailed test.

Our test statistic is:
$t=\frac{(6.65-7.5)\sqrt{10}}{2}=-1.343 \implies t \ge -2.235$, from where we see the test statistic t is not in the rejection region, therefore we fail to reject the null hypothesis.

**My questions are:**

- Is my solution correct?
- Do I have to find optimal critical region before test the hypothesises?
- What does the last part mean "Find approximation of the observed p-value., and how do I find such approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your first part of  solution we must receive for duplex confidence interwal quantile: $ z_{\alpha}: \phi(\alpha)= 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}.$

To second of part
J'll make use **program R**

$$> data<-c(8.7,7.0,4.0,7.6,3.0,8.1,6.4,6.1,9.4,6.2)$$
$$> X10 = mean(data)$$
$$> X10 $$
$$[1] 6.65 $$
$$ > u10 = (6.65 -7.5)/(2/sqrt(10))$$
$$ > u10 $$
$$ [1] -1.343968 $$
$$ > 1 - 0.01/2 $$
$$ [1] 0.995 $$
$$ > k = qnorm(0.995)$$
$$ > k $$
$$ [1] 2.575829 $$

Value of statistic

$$ u_{10} = -1,34 \notin (-\infty, -2,58> \cup <2,58, \infty)$$

There are no reasons to reject $ H_{0} $ and to receive $ H_{1}.$

Comment: Thanks! So basically I've forgotten to divide the $\alpha$ by 2. Other than that, I assume it's all good as a method. Do you know anything about that last part, namely the approximation of the p-value?

Comment: Nikola    compute \theta_{0} (centre of confidence interval) and then probability p(x) = P(X_{10}-\theta_{0}|\geq |6.65-\theta_{0}||\theta = theta_{0}) = P( |Z|\geq |Z_{0}|).